# Convert shapefile to WGS84

Tags: r, wgs84, ggmap

I have a [shapefile](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/download/bytes/nysd_15b.zip) with shapelength and shapearea, and would like to convert to WGS84 to use with ggmap.

[image]

Eventually, I would like to get plot google map of individual regions of the shapefile, and overlay it with other date

What can I use in R program to do this, i.e. convert to WGS84?

Comment: Note: The WKID is EPSG:2263, NAD83 / New York Long Island (ftUS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use functions from the `sp` and `rgdal` packages. Assuming your shape file is named *myshp*

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
proj4string(myshp) # Gives the CRS of the data 
myshp=spTransform(myshp,CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")) # To convert it to WGS84
```

`ggplot2` input has to be a DataFrame, to convert a SpatialDataFrame to a DataFrame named *mydf*, run

```
library(ggplot2)
mydf=fortify(myshp,byid="your id variable") # Converting the SpatialDataFrame to a DataFrame
myshp$id=row.names(myshp) # Adding your SpatialDataFrame data to the DataFrame
mydf=merge(mydf,myshp@data,by="id",all=T)
```

Comment: Will try this very soon

Comment: When I execute `proj4string(nysd)` I get `Error: object 'nysd' not found`

Comment: I downloaded shapefile from http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/download/bytes/nysd_15b.zip

Comment: `proj4string()` uses a SpatialObject as input. To load the spatial object use `setwd("your working directory");myshp=readOGR(dsn=getwd(),layer="nysd")`. Then run `proj4string(nysd)`, your CRS is NAD83.

Comment: This certainly helps